# Three.js tween camera.lookat

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

I'm attempting to tween the camera.lookAt in Three.js using Tween.js with little success.

This works

```
    selectedHotspot = object;

    var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.lookAt( object.position),600).start();
```

But rotates the camera directly to the object.position.

How do I get a nice smooth rotation?

This is the render function

```
  function update() {

    lat = Math.max(-85, Math.min(85, lat));
    phi = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - lat);
    theta = THREE.Math.degToRad(lon);

    target.x = 512 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
    target.y = 512 * Math.cos(phi);
    target.z = 512 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);


    if(!selectedHotspot)
        camera.lookAt(target);


    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

UPDATE

OK I can't actually tween the camera on anything. I think there must be something else wrong. Should there be something else in the render function?

Comment: You are not hooking up your update method anywhere? The reason it "works" is because it does nothing but actually SET camera.lookAt(...) to the end location.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your code should look something like this:

```
// backup original rotation
var startRotation = new THREE.Euler().copy( camera.rotation );

// final rotation (with lookAt)
camera.lookAt( object.position );
var endRotation = new THREE.Euler().copy( camera.rotation );

// revert to original rotation
camera.rotation.copy( startRotation );

// Tween
new TWEEN.Tween( camera ).to( { rotation: endRotation }, 600 ).start();
```

Comment: Thank you. It still goes straight there, no nice tween. Any ideas?

Comment: Should it be `new TWEEN.Tween(camera.rotation).to({x: endRotation.x, y: endRotation.y, z: endRotation.z}, 500).start()` now?

Answer (score 5):

Quaternion version of mrdoob's answer

```
// backup original rotation
var startRotation = camera.quaternion.clone();

// final rotation (with lookAt)
camera.lookAt( lookAt );
var endRotation = camera.quaternion.clone();

// revert to original rotation
camera.quaternion.copy( startRotation );

// Tween
var lookAtTween = new TWEEN.Tween( camera.quaternion ).to( endRotation, 600 ).start();
```

Comment: Works very well on three.js 0.98.

Comment: Was experiencing a weird camera roll/unnecessary rotation with the accepted answer, but not with this quaternion solution. Thank you!

Comment: This works well, the only problem is that the camera snaps back to its original starting position when clicking on another element to which the camera must animate afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

For a positional tween (but you get the gist) I am using this code which does have a duration parameter and does move the camera smoothly:

```
function setupTween (position, target, duration)
{
    TWEEN.removeAll();    // remove previous tweens if needed

    new TWEEN.Tween (position)
        .to (target, duration)
        .easing (TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.InOut)
        .onUpdate (
            function() {
                // copy incoming position into capera position
                camera.position.copy (position);
            })
        .start();
}
```

and I call it like so:

```
setupTween (camera.position.clone(), new THREE.Vector3 (x, y, z), 7500);
```

to get a 7.5 seconds smooth tween.

Answer (score 1):

I use controls.target to tween camera'rotation and it work well.

```
createjs.Tween.get(controls.target)
.to({
  x: tweenPos.x,
  y: tweenPos.y - 11,
  z: tweenPos.z + 0.001
}, 800,createjs.Ease.linear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

I gave up trying to tween the camera and instead added

```
if (target.y < selectedHotspot.position.y - 2)
        lat += 0.1;
    else if (target.y > selectedHotspot.position.y + 2)
            lat -= 0.1; 

    if (target.x < selectedHotspot.position.x - 5)
        lon += 0.5;
    else if (target.x > selectedHotspot.position.x + 5)
        lon -= 0.5;
    else {

        camera.lookAt(selectedHotspot.position);

        if (camera.fov > selectedHotspot.bubble.distance*0.05){
            camera.fov -= 0.1;

        }
        if(sceneReady)
            loadScene();
    }

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

To a function called in the render loop. This works well.