# three.js, tween camera and mousemove event

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I'm trying my hands on three.js

I am moving the camera using a tween, and it works quite good.
At the end of the animation, however, the camera jumps back to its initial position.

I found out that the mousemove event was causing that behavior.
How can i fix this problem and keep both the tween movement and the mouse move?

I have constructed my three.js based on [this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_points_sprites.html);

**Mousemove declared inside render function**

```
function render() {

    camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.04;
    camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.04;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    TWEEN.update();

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

**Tween movement**

```
    function setupTween (position, target, duration) {
    TWEEN.removeAll();

    new TWEEN.Tween (position)
            .to (target, duration)
            .easing (TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
            .onUpdate (
                    function() {
                        // copy incoming position into camera position
                        camera.position.copy (position);
                    })
            .start();
};
```

> [tween function source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277919/three-js-tween-camera-lookat)

**UPDATE**

Complete working code:

```
<script>

    var container,
            i,
            camera,
            scene,
            renderer,
            particles,
            geometry,
            materials = [],
            color,
            sprite,
            size,
            mouseX = 0,
            mouseY = 0,
            isTweening,
            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    // +++++ three.js +++++
    // +++++ +++++ +++++ +++++ +++++
    function init() {
        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.5, 2000 );
        camera.position.set (0,0,1900);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000000, 0.0005 );
        geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        for ( i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {
            var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
            vertex.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
            vertex.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
            vertex.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
            geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
        }




        sprite = textureLoader.load( "circle.png" );
        color  = [0.90, 0.05, 0.8];
        size   = 8.5;
        materials = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: size, map: sprite, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, depthTest: false, transparent : false } );
        materials.color.setHSL( color[0], color[1], color[2] );
        particles = new THREE.Points( geometry, materials );
        scene.add( particles );


        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    }
    function onWindowResize() {
        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }
    function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
        mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();
    }

    function startTween() {

        isTweening = false;

        var target = new THREE.Vector3(getRandomNumber(), getRandomNumber(), getRandomNumber());

        new TWEEN.Tween (camera.position.clone())
                .to (target, 1000)
                .easing (TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
                .onUpdate( function() {
                    camera.position.copy(this);
                })
                .onStart ( function() {
                    isTweening = true;
                })
                .onComplete ( function() {
                    isTweening = false;
                })
                .start();
    }

    function getRandomNumber() {
        // get a number between -1000 and -500 and 500 and 1000
        return ( Math.random() * 500 + 500 ) * ( Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1 );
    }

    function render() {

        if(!isTweening && (mouseX || mouseY)) {
            // more a generic approach, not just transforming x and y (maybe it needs to be improved a bit)
            var upVector = camera.up.clone().transformDirection(camera.matrix);
            var forwardVector = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(scene.position, camera.position).normalize();
            var rightVector = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(forwardVector, upVector);

            camera.translateOnAxis(rightVector, mouseX);
            camera.translateOnAxis(upVector, -mouseY);
            mouseX = mouseY = 0;
        }
        camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        TWEEN.update();

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

    init();
    animate();


    setTimeout(function(){
        startTween();
    },2500);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should only update the position by the mousemove event, when it's not tweening. So you need to check if its currently tweening or not.

```js
var isTweening = false;

new TWEEN.Tween (camera.position)
    .to (target, duration)
    .easing (TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
    .onStart ( function() {
        isTweening = true;
    })
    .onComplete ( function() {
        isTweening = false;
    })
    .start();

// in your render loop
function render() {

    if (!isTweening) {
        camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.04;
        camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.04;
    }
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    TWEEN.update();

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

You don't need to set an `onUpdate` function and copy the new position to `camera.position`. You can just pass over `camera.position` to the tween and it will work.

**EDIT:**

I didn't see the link to example. Now, I know which kind of navigation is used (which is actually used in a lot of three.js examples). It's not the mousemove event that is causing your problem, it's this kind of calculating the new camera position (`camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.04;`). So, I changed the code of the example a bit, especially the navigation. Here are the important parts:

```js
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    mouseX = (event.movementX * 0.5) || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
    mouseY = (event.movementY * 0.5) || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;
}

function render() {

    if(!isTweening && (mouseX || mouseY)) {
        // more a generic approach, not just transforming x and y (maybe it needs to be improved a bit)
        var upVector = camera.up.clone().transformDirection(camera.matrix);
        var forwardVector = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(scene.position, camera.position).normalize();
        var rightVector = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(forwardVector, upVector);

        camera.translateOnAxis(rightVector, mouseX);
        camera.translateOnAxis(upVector, -mouseY);
        mouseX = mouseY = 0;
    }
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    TWEEN.update();
}

function startTween() {

    isTweening = false;

    var target = new THREE.Vector3(getRandomNumber(), getRandomNumber(), getRandomNumber());

    new TWEEN.Tween (camera.position.clone())
        .to (target, 1000)
        .easing (TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
        .onUpdate( function() {
            camera.position.copy(this);
        })
        .onStart ( function() {
            isTweening = true;
        })
        .onComplete ( function() {
            isTweening = false;
        })
        .start();
}

function getRandomNumber() {
    // get a number between -1000 and -500 and 500 and 1000
    return ( Math.random() * 500 + 500 ) * ( Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1 );
}
```

And you are right about `TWEEN.onUpdate`: you need to copy the new values to `camera.position`. My earlier approach do also work, but then all of the functionality of `THREE.Vector3` gets lost. I didn't realize that until now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does not work, as long as `isTweening` variable is set to `true`, the camera jumps back to its initial position.
Also, i do not see the animation if i do not update the camera position inside the `onUpdate` callback

Comment: Hm, I'm also tweening my camera and it works without `onUpdate`: `new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to(newpos, 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();` (I just copied it from my code). And I barely understand, why you substract `camera.position` from `mouseX`? Can you please setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: I will asap. About the mouseX subtraction: follow the link i provided in my question, it does move the camera based in the mouse's direction

Comment: Now, I've spent more time than I wanted to, to change the example a bit. Have look at my updated answer.

Comment: Excuse me for being so late. I really appreciate your help. I will try it as soon as possible

Comment: It seems to work, thank you. I had to use my old mouse move function though. I will post a complete example on my question.